# Custom tips in Ext.chart.Chart (ext-js 4)

Tags: extjs, tooltip

I'd like to reproduce something like this (in terms of `Ext.chart.Tip`):

[image: vertical line tips]

in *ext-js 4*. The problem is that I have no clue where to start. What is the most effective way to achieve this result?